# How to get the newly added package into python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment for python and hence i activate like this

```
#source  myName/bin/activate
```

In the host machine, i have installed this package

```
#sudo pip install scikit-image
```

In the virtual environment, i m unable to access scikit-image. How can i get the newly added package into the existing virtual environment?

Comment: activate virtualenv and install package via pip?

Comment: you need to do it the other way around: activate the virtualenv, THEN install the package

Comment: @Reishin Can virtual environment access the host machine packages?.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster yes, use `--system-site-packages` on virtualenv creation

Comment: @Reishin, can i recreate the same one which is already created?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip`without `sudo` in order to install it in your environment. When you use `sudo` you become `root`, then your packages are installed as `root`.

Comment: you mean to say in host machine you want me to install without sudo?

Comment: If you install it with a virtual environment, you don't use `sudo` because when you use sudo, the packages get installed in `/usr/local/lib/pythonversion/dist-packages` and when you are using a virtual environment it is usually installed in your `/home/username/something/your-environment/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your [PATH becomes different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169253) when running a program with `sudo` rights. Therefore, you install the package to your root python executable even though you activated the virtual env. To check this try:

```
source myName/bin/activate
which pip
sudo which pip
```

The last two outputs will differ.
To install the package to your virtual environment, simply run:

```
# Activate the Virtual Environment
source myName/bin/activate 

# Double-check that you use Pip of the Virtual Env.
which pip

# Install the package to the Virtual Env.
pip install --upgrade scikit-image

# Double-check that it was installed correctly
pip list
```

**Sidenote:**
Using `pip` with `sudo` rights is not recommended since you execute code downloaded from an online repository with `sudo` rights (More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594)).